# PHP extension "curl" must be loaded. PHP extension "soap" must be loaded

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to magento and currently I am getting "PHP Extension curl must be loaded" error during magento installation.
Can you help me?

Comment: is this your own server or hosted with a company? linux or windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your server does not have curl installed on it you can type one of the following commands to install it:

For Debian/Ubuntu based systems you can type below command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

For RedHat/CentOS based systems you can type (as root)

```
yum install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

This should install curl and have it start to work for you.

Comment: If you tell me what flavor of Linux you are using I can probably help you out a little more as to what commands you have to do in order to do the install.

Comment: for PHP7 it's just php-curl package

Answer (score 1):

remove ';' from extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini , maybe you don't have active de mod.

Do  and look if you have it active.

Comment: .dll implies windows usage which is not supported by Magento

Answer (score 1):

Before installing Magento or any other system take a look at the [system requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements):

For **Magento**:

Supported Operating Systems:

- Linux x86, x86-64

Supported Web Servers:

- Apache 1.3.x
- Apache 2.0.x
- Apache 2.2.x

Supported Browsers:

- Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 and above
- Mozilla Firefox 2.0 and above
- Apple Safari 2.x
- Google Chrome
- Adobe Flash browser plug-in should be installed

PHP Compatibility:

- 5.2

Required extensions:

- PDO_MySQL
- simplexml
- mcrypt
- hash
- GD
- DOM
- iconv
- **curl**
- SOAP (if Webservices API is to be used)
- Safe_mode off
- Memory_limit no less than 256Mb (preferably 512)

MySQL:

- 4.1.20 or newer
- InnoDB storage engine
  SSL:
- If HTTPS is used to work in the admin, SSL certificate should be valid. Self-signed SSL certificates are not supported
  Server - hosting - setup:
- Ability to run scheduled jobs (crontab) with PHP 5
- Ability to override options in .htaccess files

To install CURL check [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php) depending on your platform

Answer (score 1):

1: Find extension=php_soap.dll in php.ini and remove the semicolon(;)

2: Restart your Server

Answer (score 0):

[Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048740/2334352) should work fine with PHP5, but if you're on PHP7 (for Debian/Ubuntu based systems):

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Then restart your server.

Also, no need to uncomment the extension in `php.ini` once this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding an answer, not enough points to comment on che-azeh's answer, which should be:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-curl
```